# Button vertically centers content but div does not

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

The following vertically centers the inner div

**HTML**

```
<button class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello<br>World
    </div>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: dashed 1px black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
   background: #ccc;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draperp/WP8um/)

[image: button]

But if I use a `div` instead of a `button` for the outer element,

[image: div]

For semantic reasons, I want a `div` not a `button`.

**What CSS styles do I need to add to the `.outer` class to produce the same vertical-alignment styling that the button had?**

I need this to work in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I would like to see what you did, if you don't mind, in a fiddle may be

Answer (score 0):

This is What you need: Link: http://jsfiddle.net/WP8um/2/

OR If you don't want margin on outer div you can use top,left,bottom,right properties. http://jsfiddle.net/WP8um/3/

**CSS**

```
.outer {
 display: inline;
 margin:25%; 
 background: none;
 outline: dashed 1px black;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
}


 .inner {
 background: #ccc;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 50% 0;
}
```

Comment: The outer element's size is fixed at 200px by 200px. In my example, the outer element's size is based on the size of its parent.

Comment: You can use percentage based on the size of the parent. What is the size of parent ?

Comment: In this case, the parent is `body`. Compare your JSFiddle to mine and you'll see that the sizes differ (depending on the window size).

Comment: Div is a block element. It'll need some size while button was inline element.

Comment: 50% margin won't do the job, because it is taken from the top of the element, so the div won't be centred properly